# Fast way to generate matrix of sampled rows with or without replacement in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization, resampling

I have some input row. To perform some numerical statistical tests I need a lot of samples of the same size, which are sampled from the input row with or without replacement. I have some very straightforward code, which do it:

```
inputRow = [1 3 4 2 7 5 8 6];
rowSize = numel(inputRow);
nPermutations = 10;
permutedMatrix = nan(nPermutations,rowSize);

replaceFlag = true;

permutedMatrix(1,:) = inputRow;
for iPerm = 2:nPermutations
    permutedMatrix(iPerm,:) = datasample(inputRow,rowSize,'Replace',replaceFlag);
end
```

My question is: **Is it possible to generate desired matrix without for loops?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps,

resampling with replacement:

```
input=[2 3 4 2 3 4];

len=size(input,2);
number_of_permutations=10;

rand_idx=randi(len,1,len*number_of_permutations);
permutation_matrix=zeros(len,number_of_permutations);
permutation_matrix(:)=input(rand_idx);
permutation_matrix=permutation_matrix';
```

this is reampling without replacement

```
input=[2 3 4 2 3 4];

len=size(input,2);
number_of_permutations=10;

rand_idx=repmat(randperm(len,len),1,number_of_permutations);
permutation_matrix=zeros(len,number_of_permutations);
permutation_matrix(:)=input(rand_idx);
permutation_matrix=permutation_matrix';
```